# Why I got a bad result image background shadow?

Tags: shadows

I am making this model but I got a bad final image when I used background and casted shadow on it. I think that I did everything well in materials and scene nodes. I attached blender file. that nodes I did is just to have a shadow on table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure it's not just the samples? How many samples did you render with?

Comment: I suspect the issue could be with the Divide node that you have in there - what's that trying to do? It's difficult to tell without more information.

Comment: Hello, I think it is not sampling I used 1000 and it is the same problem.

Comment: @RichSedman I did attached the blender file check it. it is plastic transparent and other nodes for casting shadow.

Comment: The problem looks to be with the Object Index - seemingly due to conflicting close geometry inside the bowl. I can't look into it in more detail at the moment but can take a more detailed look later if nobody else can help.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in index as I know because I am new so I wish you can check the blender file and find it @RichSedman

Comment: @NajebAlbakar I believe I've spotted the issue. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due to the Alpha Threshold of the Render Layer affecting the Object Index.

The Alpha Threshold controls whether transparent objects in the scene register on certain passes of the render layer.

Anything greater than or equal to the Alpha Threshold will be included in that pass, anything less than the threshold will not. In your example scene the Alpha Threshold is set to 0.5 and this results in the Object Index pass from not being consistently present. By reducing the threshold (ie, to 0.2 in the screenshot below), the Object Index is included correctly and the compositor is able to process the index correctly.

[image: alpha threshold]

Comment: It works perfectly, Super! thank you for explaining it also.

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Normally that shouldn't cause an issue but in this case I think the topology of the Cylinder object (the container and its contents) was causing it to flip between a high enough alpha for it to register and a too low alpha so it didn't. Also, in Material.002 there's an Add Shader that I'm not sure what it's doing, feeding its output into the Factor of a Mix Shader - you should ensure that Shader sockets always only connect to other Shader sockets - although that didn't cause a problem in this case.

Comment: I got it now thank to your answer. about the add shader I am not sure about it also I thought just to make next stig which is reflection on it being better on edges. Thanks again